# Why can't prime numbers satisfy the Pythagoras Theorem? That is, why can't a set of 3 prime numbers be a Pythagorean triplet?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

Suppose $a$, $b$ and $c$ are three prime numbers.

How to prove that $a^2 + b^2 \neq c^2$?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE, Tell us what have you tried and where are you stuck exactly. We'll be more than happy to help you

Comment: Although many answerers have already given you essentially complete solutions for this question, in general you would learn much better if you describe what you have tried, so that people can give the appropriate guidance for you to find the solution, because reading someone else's solution never helps you gain the experience of trying and learning what techniques work and what doesn't.

Comment: Okay, I got to this part- I assume a,b,c are all odd and that a^2+b^2 is even so when a,b,c are odd primes it's not true.

Comment: Where I'm stuck is- I assume a=2, and b is odd= 2k+1, so a^2+b^2 is 4k^2+4k+5. How to prove this is not a perfect square??

Comment: @AkankshitaDash: There are a number of ways, but one very useful technique is to show that it is between two consecutive squares, because then it cannot itself be a square since $x \mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing. Can you do this?

Comment: I don't think I can :( I'll try though!However, this is a homework assignment and I think the tutors want us to do it in a specific way..

Comment: @AkankshitaDash: There is no such thing as a specific way. Any solution that is mathematically correct has to be accepted, as long as you don't use something that hasn't been proven yet. You should already know a square that is 'close' to $4k^2+4k+5$, so you just need to show that it is in-between that square and the next.

Comment: Will (2k+1)^2 and (2k+2)^2 work?

Comment: Side B is always a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 41):

**Hint:** If $a,b$ are odd primes, $a^2 + b^2 > 2$ and is even.
Hence, the only possibilities are
$$
2^2 + 2^2 = c^2
\\
2^2 + b^2 = c^2
$$
and they are not possible either because $c - b \ge 2 \implies c^2>2^2 + b^2$.

Comment: Sweet, concise and easy to understand. +1

Comment: That $2^2+b^2=c^2$ is not possible can also be proved by $b^2=(c-2)(c+2),$ and that $b$ is odd.

Comment: indeed. the interesting part is the first one, obviously.

Comment: Very easy to understand! But if you have to write a rigorous proof for this one, will this do?

Comment: well, you'll have to elaborate a little. But without the details, all is here.

Comment: Sure :) Actually this is for a homework assignment, so I was trying to write it in a more rigorous way- assuming a=2 and b=2k+1. Where I'm stuck is- proving a^2+b^2 is not a perfect square, i.e 4k^2+4k+5 is not a perfect square. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @AkankshitaDash well, as I told you: if $2^2 + b^2 = c^2$ is a solution, then $b,c$ are odd. As they are different and primes, their difference is $\ge 2$. Then: $c^2 \ge (b+2)^2 > 2^2 + b^2$. It is impossible.

Comment: You should've said $a^2 + b^2 > 2^2$ instead of $a^2 + b^2 > 2$.

Answer (score 16):

From $a^2+b^2=c^2$ we get $a^2=c^2-b^2=(c+b)(c-b)$, i.e. a factorization of $a^2$ into two distinct factors $c+b>c-b$. The only such factorizations for the square of a prime is $a^2\cdot 1$, i.e. we conclude $c-b=1$, hence $b=2$, $c=3$. But then $a^2=5$, qea.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get this bit- The only such factorizations for the square of a prime is a2⋅1

Comment: @AkankshitaDash: There are 3 possible ways to divide up the prime factors of $a^2$ into two factors. You can try all of them to see that only the one given by *Hagen von Eitzen* works.

Answer (score 8):

The sum of two odd numbers are even, so one of the numbers must be $2$.

If $a$ or $b$ are $2$ we have $a^2+4=c^2$ or $4=(c+a)(c-a)$ Since $c-a$ and $c+a$ have the same parity, this is impossible.

If $c=2$ we have $a^2+b^2=4$ but since $a$ and $b$ are positive, both must be $1$, but $1^2+1^2=2$.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with what you mean by parity. Could you possibly include a resource to read more about this topic?

Comment: @brad Parity just means "odd or evenness" to say two numbers have the same parity, is to say they are either both odd, or both even.

Comment: +1 for avoiding the temptation of sophisticated arguments. You could not resist factoring $c^2-a^2$ though; I think my answer gives a somewhat simpler argument why $a=2$ or $b=2$ is impossible.

Answer (score 6):

Primes are all odd expect $2$, so if $a, b, c$ don't contain $2$, $a^2 + b^2$ is even but $c^2$ is odd, then $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ can't be true.

Of course if $c=2$, then $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ can't be true.

If $a = 2$, then $c>b$ then $c^2 - b^2 \geq (b+2)^2 - b^2 = 4b + 4 > a^2 $

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**
    
All Pythagorean triples can be written as:

$$  a = k\cdot(m^2 - n^2) ,\ \, b = k\cdot(2mn) ,\ \, c = k\cdot(m^2 + n^2),$$

where $m, n$, and $k$ are positive integers with $m \gt n, m − n$ odd, and with $m$ and $n$ coprime.

Comment: proof of this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Proof_of_Euclid.27s_formula

Answer (score 3):

On cannot have $a^2+b^2=c^2$ if $a,b,c$ are all odd. Since $2$ is the only even prime number, one of $a,b,c$ would have to be $2$. But since $2$ is the smallest prime number clearly $c$ cannot be$~2$; furthermore for any $n\geq2$ one has the inequalities $n^2<n^2+4<(n+1)^2$ showing that $n^2+2^2$ is not a square, so $a$ or $b$ cannot be $2$ either.

Answer (score 2):

because one of them must be even number.