# Show that for any prime numbers $p,q,r$, one has $p^2+q^2 \ne r^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Not sure how to start. Prove by induction? Please help!

Comment: What do you know about most prime numbers? What do you know about the difference between two squares? Show that you have thought about the problem before asking others to solve it. Induction is not a natural method for primes, because they are irregularly distributed. You need to work out what you do know that might be useful.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of: [Why can't prime numbers satisfy the Pythagoras Theorem? That is, why can't a set of 3 prime numbers be a Pythagorean triplet?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991947/why-cant-prime-numbers-satisfy-the-pythagoras-theorem-that-is-why-cant-a-set)

Answer (score 11):

Since $p^2 = r^2 - q^2 = (r+q)(r-q)$ we reach an easy contradiction. (What are the factors of $p^2$?)

Comment: What if $r-q=1$?

Comment: If $r - q = 1$ then $r=3$ and $q=2$. Then what is $p$?

Comment: Yes, but you haven't addressed this in your answer.

Comment: @abiessu Seems like OP is doing homework, I'm from stackoverflow and there we don't give complete answers to homework, only nudges. Is it a different convention here?

Comment: Ah, no worries, your answer is really pretty good.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

If both $p$ and $q$ are even, then $p=q=2$ and then $r^2=8$, not possible.

If both $p$ and $q$ are odd, then $r$ must be even and so $r=2$. But then $p,q\ge 3$ and so $p^2+q^2\ge 18 > 4=r^2$.

If $p$ is even and $q$ is odd, then $r$ is odd and $p=2$ and so $4=(r-q)(r+q)$. This implies $r-q=2$ and $r+q=2$, and so $q=0$, not possible; or $r-q=1$ and $r$ is even, not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see that $p^2+q^2=3^2$ has no solutions in primes (in fact there are *no* positive integers whose squares sum to $9$).  It's also easy to see that $3^2+q^3=r^2$ (and likewise $p^2+3^2=r^2$) has no solutions in primes:  $q$ cannot be odd, since $3^2+q^2$ would then be an even number greater than $4$, but it can't be $2$ either, since $3^2+2^2=13$ is not a square.  So we can conclude that $3\not\mid pqr$.  But in that case, $p^2\equiv q^2\equiv r^2\equiv1$ mod $3$, and we see that $p^2+q^2\equiv2\not\equiv1$ mod $3$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p,q$ are both odd, then $r=2$, no solutions. If wlog $p=2$, then $4=(r-q)(r+q)$. But $r+q>4$, contradiction.